# Storing a httpcode into array using ParllelCurl in PHP

Tags: php, function, curl

I am trying to make a program which loops through a bunch of urls and returns their response code. I am using the ParallelCurl class and I went off the example on [here](http://www.codediesel.com/php/parallel-curl-execution/). My code so far is:

```
 function on_request_done($content, $url, $ch) {

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "cacert.pem");
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

}

 $max_requests = 10;

$curl_options = array(
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Parallel Curl test script',
);

$parallel_curl = new ParallelCurl($max_requests, $curl_options);

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){

  $parallel_curl->startRequest($urls[$i],'on_request_done');

    }   

$parallel_curl->finishAllRequests();
```

This code works fine, but I now want to get the value of $httpcode outside of the function and store it into an array. Any ideas on how I could do this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

U could do something like :

```
$http_codes = array();
function on_request_done($content, $url, $ch) {
    global $http_codes;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "cacert.pem");
    $http_codes[] = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

}
/*--... code  ...--*/
var_dump($http_codes);
```

Second aproach without using global would be this :

```
function on_request_done($content, $url, $ch, &$http_codes) {

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "cacert.pem");
    $http_codes[] = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

}

 $max_requests = 10;

$curl_options = array(
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Parallel Curl test script',
);

$http_codes = [];
$parallel_curl = new ParallelCurl($max_requests, $curl_options);

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){

  $parallel_curl->startRequest($urls[$i],'on_request_done', $http_codes);

    }   

$parallel_curl->finishAllRequests();
var_dump($http_codes);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I used the first way. However a slight change I had to make instead of `$http_codes[] = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);` to 
`$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);`
`array_push($http_codes, $httpcode);`